# Adding query from Twisted `enterprise.adbapi` to reactor loop created by `twistd` daemon

Tags: python, twisted

I am using the `twisted.enterprise.adbapi` inside a Twisted `.tac` plugin, and am finding that the deferred object returned for functions such as `aConnectionPool.runQuery(sqlQuery)` are not firing unless `reactor.(run)` is called. How can I add the query to the reactor loop created by `twistd` instead of calling `reactor.run()`? Is it a general procedure or is it something specific to the asynchronous database API?

edit - attached the code:

```
from twisted.application import internet, service
from zope.interface import implements
from twisted.web.iweb import IBodyProducer

from twisted.internet import defer, protocol, reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import succeed
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers

import json
import base64
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi

class StringProducer(object):
    implements(IBodyProducer)

    def __init__(self, body):
        self.body = body
        self.length = len(body)

    def startProducing(self, consumer):
        consumer.write(self.body)
        return succeed(None)

    def pauseProducing(self):
        pass

    def stopProducing(self):
        pass

def httpRequest(url, values, headers={}, method='POST'):

    agent = Agent(reactor)
    d = agent.request(method,
                      url,
                      Headers(headers),
                      StringProducer(values)
                      )

    def handle_response(response):
        if response.code == 204:
            d = defer.succeed('')
        else:
            class SimpleReceiver(protocol.Protocol):
                def __init__(s, d):
                    s.buf = ''; s.d = d
                def dataReceived(s, data):
                    s.buf += data
                    response = json.loads(data)

                    receipt = response[u'receipt']
                    if receipt[u'product_id'] == "com.domain_name.app_name.a_product_id":
                        transactionID = receipt[u'original_transaction_id']
                        date = receipt[u'original_purchase_date']
                        purchaseDate = date.strip(' Etc/GMT')
                        print transactionID
                        print purchaseDate

                        dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb', db='mydb', user='user',  passwd='passwd')
                        dOperation = dbpool.runOperation("insert into users(name, original_transaction_id, date_joined) values(%s, %s, %s)", ('testuser', transactionID, purchaseDate))

                        def finishInsert(dObject, pool):
                            print 'inserted!'
                            pool.close()
                        dOperation.addCallback(finishInsert, dbpool)

                        def insertError(dObject):
                            print 'insert error!'
                        dOperation.addErrback(insertError)

                def connectionLost(s, reason):
                    s.d.callback(s.buf)

            d = defer.Deferred()
            response.deliverBody(SimpleReceiver(d))
        return d

    d.addCallback(handle_response)

class StoreServer(protocol.Protocol):

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        a = data.split(':delimiter:')

        if a[0] == 'addToUserList':
            receiptBase64 = base64.standard_b64encode(a[1])
            jsonReceipt = json.dumps({'receipt-data':receiptBase64})

            httpRequest(
                        "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt",
                        jsonReceipt,
                        {'Content-Type': ['application/x-www-form-urlencoded']}
                        )

application = service.Application("My Server")
storeFactory = protocol.Factory()
storeFactory.protocol = StoreServer
tcpStoreServer = internet.TCPServer(30000, storeFactory)
tcpStoreServer.setServiceParent(application)
```

Comment: Pleaser attach a complete version of your tac file.  The specifics of how you are setting up adbapi are very important to understanding your problem.

Comment: Well this is really weird. I just went back and tried running it again and it worked. I swear I didn't change a thing. Should I post the code as an edit or just delete the question?

Comment: Please post the code.  It's possible that you're doing something that's not thread-safe, or that involves a race condition, and it's only working by accident.  Please describe exactly what you meant by "not firing" as well (how did you observe the lack of firing?)

Comment: By not firing, I meant that a callback I added to the returned deferred object (`finishInsert` in the code) did not print out 'inserted!' when I was testing in `twistd -ny`. When I stopped twistd, there was also no sign of any error. The connection pool and deferred object from the query were both initilized but the callback was never called.

Answer (score 2):

Your code makes a new `ConnectionPool` for every request it issues.  The new `ConnectionPool` creates its own new thread pool to run queries in, and has to set up a new connection to the database.

This means you effectively have no connection pool.  You just have a lot of connections that you create and use once.  Also, the errback, `insertError`, does not close the pool.

These things combined mean that there is no limit on the number of threads/connections that might be created at once, except for the limit imposed by your system on how much memory you can allocate, or how many sockets you can open.  When you run into one of those limits, things won't be pretty.

It also means that every query error leaks a few threads and connections (`ConnectionPool` sets up 3 threads/connections when it starts).  After enough errors, you won't be able to create any more threads or connections, so you won't be able to query your database any more.  Your query is simple, and you might think that errors aren't very likely, but MySQL tends to disconnect clients somewhat at random (and maybe you were at least somewhat aware of this, since you *did* add the errback to report the failure).

The intended use of a `ConnectionPool` is to create one (or two, or some other small, fixed number) and then re-use it for all of your queries.  Whether these problems are related to the ones that you originally observed or not, I don't know, but they are probably problems you should fix.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and the catch on thread leaking. Ah, hence connection _pool_. So I guess I should pass the single `connectionPool` instance to the class `__init__()` and keep a reference.